# remove() in C returning "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, stat

I have been facing this issue for about 2 weeks now and through all the searching I've done (which has been very extensive mind you) I've yet to find a solution to it. Here is my function:

```
void delete( int sock, char *fileName ) {
       unsigned int tid = (unsigned int)pthread_self();        

       if ( fileExists( fileName ) != 0 ) {
               char msg[20];
               strcpy( msg, "ERROR NO SUCH FILE\n" );
               send( sock, msg, strlen( msg ), 0 );
               printf( "[thread %u] Sent: %s", tid, msg );
       }

       if ( remove( fileName) != 0 ) {
               send( sock, FAILURE, strlen( FAILURE ), 0 );
               printf( "[thread %u] Sent: %s", tid, FAILURE );
       } else {
               send( sock, SUCCESS, strlen( SUCCESS ), 0 );
               printf( "[thread %u] Sent: %s", tid, SUCCESS );
       }       
}
```

This function is used in a part of a FTP server I am writing in C, where one of the commands the client can enter is to delete a particular file from the server storage (which is a folder labeled ".storage/" on my hard drive). The code for the fileExists() function is as follows below:

```
int fileExists( char *fileName ) {
        struct stat buf;
        return ( stat( fileName, &buf ) == 0 );
}
```

When I run my code and tell the server to delete a file (which I know for a fact exists), the `remove()` function returns the error "No such file or directory" (in an older version of my code I used `perror()` to figure out what the error was). However, the `fileExists()` function returns 0, meaning that the file does exist.

Has anyone ever experienced the problem where a `stat()` reports that a file exists but `remove()` doesn't? I'm really pulling my hair out trying to figure this one out, and I have yet to find a solution for it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: Thank you for your responses. It turns out that `remove()` didn't seem to like the null terminators on the strings I was sending it. However, I do agree that my `fileExists()` function is a bit misleading. I will change that to make it easier (if only for myself).

Comment: If the file exists, stat() returns 0, then fileExists() returns true (not zero) and your test in delete() is backwards.  My personal opinion is that you stick to return 0 on success.  Much less confusing.

Comment: Use `access()` instead of `stat()` in your case.

Comment: What is sock? (I hope: a filedescriptor for an UDP socket)

Comment: If your problem is solved then you should either accept one of the given answers, or write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`stat()` returns `-1` if the file does not exist (or there was another error). In that case `stat(fileName, &buf) == 0` is `0`. Therefore you should replace

```
   if ( fileExists( fileName ) != 0 ) {
```

with

```
   if ( fileExists( fileName ) == 0 ) {
```

to check for an error condition.

If you "know for fact that the file exists" then the problem might be that `fileName` is a  relative path, which is resolved relative to the *current working directory*
of the process.

Note that you actually do not need a separate `fileExists()` function at all (and
there is a small race condition if the file is deleted between the `fileExists()`
and the `remove()` call). Better just try to remove the file, and check `errno` 
if that fails:

```
void delete( int sock, char *fileName ) {
       unsigned int tid = (unsigned int)pthread_self();        


       if ( remove( fileName) != 0 ) {
               if (errno == ENOENT) {
                    // file does not exist 
                    char msg[20];
                    strcpy( msg, "ERROR NO SUCH FILE\n" );
                    send( sock, msg, strlen( msg ), 0 );
                    printf( "[thread %u] Sent: %s", tid, msg );

               } else {
                    // some other error ...
                    send( sock, FAILURE, strlen( FAILURE ), 0 );
                    printf( "[thread %u] Sent: %s", tid, FAILURE );
               }
       } else {
               send( sock, SUCCESS, strlen( SUCCESS ), 0 );
               printf( "[thread %u] Sent: %s", tid, SUCCESS );
       }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is from the manual for `stat`..

> On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

You are checking if zero is returned in your function..

```
int fileExists( char *fileName ) {
    struct stat buf;
    return ( stat( fileName, &buf ) == 0 );
}
```

Suppose a file exists..then your return condition will return `true`(non NULL value) because `stat` will return `0` and that satisfies the condition..
But this check will obviously be true..

> if ( fileExists( fileName ) != 0 ) {

and your coed prints 'error file down not exist`..

Change your condition to

> if ( fileExists( fileName ) == 0 ) {

Answer (score 1):

When I used `remove()` with a variable (such as `char* fileName`) it failed, reporting the error as `No such file or directory`. However, when I run the function with a string literal (aka something like `remove( "abc.txt" );`), it succeeds. After much testing, it seemed that `remove()` was not a fan of the null terminator. Which I am currently believing was the root of my problems.